# How to launch background lftp session in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, stdout

I want to associate the FTP session with the file descriptor, which would refer to it throughout the script. Including cycles.

For example something like this. But it did not get to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#start of script
exec {ftpdescriptor}<> >(lftp -u $ftpuser,$ftppass $ftpip/$ftptd)

# code

(echo "ls" 1>&"$ftpdecriptor")> myanswer

# code

echo "bye" 1>&"$ftpdecriptor"
exec {ftpdescriptor}>&-
exit 0
# end of script
```

It works, but the answer is always going to stdout..

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem so

```
# start of script
ftpout=$(mktemp)
$timetowaitftp
exec {ftpin}> >(lftp -u $ftpuser,$ftppass $ftpip/$ftptd > $ftpout)
printf >&$ftpin "set net:timeout 10\n"
function ftpio {
    :>$ftpout
    printf >&$ftpin "$1\n"
    i=0
    while [ ! $2 ] && [ ! -s $ftpout ] && [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
        # echo "waiting answer from ftp 1 sec.."
        sleep 1;
        let i=i+1
    done
}

# code

ftpio "cd /modx" "nowait" # no output of cd command.
ftpio "ls"
cat $ftpout
sleep 15
ftpio "pwd"
cat $ftpout
#ftpio "put /var/www/vhosts/modx/backups/20160121.113318.tar.gz" "nowait" # 12Gb
#ftpio "put /var/www/vhosts/modx/backups/20150930.092338.tar.gz" "nowait" # 800mb

# /code

# end of script
printf 1>&"$ftpin" "bye\n"
exec {ftpin}>&-
rm $ftpout
```

ftpin - named descriptor

ftpout - temp file with last answer of ftp